# Who creates /home/<user>/Public every (boot) time?

Tags: ftp, samba, debian-squeeze

I have a **debian squeeze** machine on which, after every boot, there is an empty directory "Public" (yes, capital P) in all the /home-Folders.

It obviously looks SMB- or FTP-related, but I can't figure out who or what is responsible for its creation. The only hint I have is that some other administrator has installed the packages `samba, gsambad, gadmintools, winbind` via apt-get and purged all of them again a short time later.

(Though gadmintools is a metapackage including more stuff for FTP, BIND, DHCP, Squid and so on, there are none of these services running on the system anymore. Meaning, all of the dependent services of gadmintools have been purged as well.)

I can't find anything in /etc/init.d/ or /etc/rc* that would suggest anything of said services survived and lives to create directories. Also, I can't find the string "Public" in /etc/ or /var/ or whereever, hoped it would be defined in some config file. I even used `chattr +i` on the directory, hoping to find someone complaining in syslog at boot time, but to no avail.

Can anyone give me more clues about this?

Comment: Any contents in the Public folder?  Is there a smb.conf with [public] path = /home/public ? (Not capitalised though). Any reasults in grepping for uplick (without the 'p') ?

Comment: Empty. And there is no smb.conf or similar file.

Comment: is this a user named 'user' or does 'user' refer to a variable user name '%user%'

Comment: If you do not mind being extremely inefficient: (One grep process per file, it is hard to do worse).  `find /path/to/directory -exec grep -c "ublic" {} /dev/null \;`  (optionally without the -c). Alternative: `grep -Rl ublic /path/to/dir`, but that might not work on every system.

Comment: /path/to/directory would mean / here and I already did that. Might have missed something in the loads of output though (python-stuff alone has a lot of "public" in it). But anyhow, I apparently solved the thing in the meantime. `ps -ef | grep share` brought up some apache-processes that were fiddeling with WebDAV and gnome-user-share stuff. Haven't given it much thought, just de/reinstalled apache2* and no trace left of Public-dirs. But thank you very much anyways.

Comment: Good to hear you solved it. (Did not post with / because that would include /dev and thus /dev/zero. Grepping that might take some time).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Self-answering this one:

`ps -ef | grep share` brought up some apache-processes that were fiddeling with WebDAV and *gnome-user-share* stuff. (Meaning that the apache processes mentioned those on their command line shown by ps.) Haven't given it much thought, just de/reinstalled any apache2* packages. No more Public's after booting now.

Still, thanks for thinking about it.